Restored account won't allow messaging in Teams - "Unknown User" and "Failed to Send"
We are seeing some issues regarding a tenant where the user accounts had to be deleted and re-created.
We have restored the user accounts (using the Exchange CLI restore commands) so that the user account, mailbox, and contact details were all re-created from a backup mailbox via the Retention Policies.
Everything seems to be working fine EXCEPT - we cannot message each other in Teams.
Any attempt to start a "Chat" with anyone in our own directly results in the User Account name changing to "Unknown User". Trying to actually post / send a message in that chat results in the error "Failed to Send"

Does anyone have any ideas on how we might work to resolve this?
I have cleared my Teams Cache, Signed out and back in, and rebooted my device.
I am also seeing the same behaviour on both Web, Desktop App, and Mobile App versions of the Teams client.
